# How to manipulate dates/datetimes in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is embarrassing, but i am having a hard time doing simple manipulation of datetimes.

This is the c# version of what i basically try to achive using c++11;

```cs
DateTime date1=new DateTime(4,5,2012);
DateTime date2=new DateTIme(7,8,2013);
int day1=date1.Days;
TimeSpan ts=d2-d1;
int diffDays=ts.Days;
```

What did i try?

```c
    std::tm tm;
    tm.tm_year=113;
    tm.tm_mon=0;
    tm.tm_wday=0;

    std::time_t tt=mktime(&tm);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point then = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto e1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(now - then).count();
```

The value of e1 (379218) makes no sense what so ever.

I took a look at chrono, which is presented as the c++11 standard library for datetime but i just could not find an example of how to create a date having int year=2012, int month=2, int day=14.

PS:Is chrono sufficient for handling date/times/timezones in c++11? Is there a need for time.h?

Comment: `<chrono>` deals with time but it doesn't deal with calendars, which is what you're looking for (other than converting from `time_t`). I don't know of any calendar libraries built on top of `<chrono>` yet.

Comment: For handling dates there is the excellent `boost gregorian` library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html. Alternatively also QT has it's own date classes.

Comment: In addition to the good suggestion of using the boost library, you're welcome to try my date library described in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15146434/576911 .  Here is a direct link to it: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/date.html

Comment: The above link for my date library is out of date.  Here is the new link: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize all fields from `tm`, start with

```
std::tm tm = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Without this, the other fields (the ones you don't explicitly set afterwards) will contain arbitrary values. The conversion will also normalize values, which mean that if the field `tm_hour` contains 123456789, it will add so many hours to the day you specified. This is how those nonsense-values for `e1` can be explained. If you initialize all fields explicitly, it will allow your example to return meaningful values, although you might need to set more fields like `isdst` to make it correct for all cases.

I have to admit that I haven't used `chrono` so far as I find the required syntax overly verbose and I keep using my own classes to wrap the C-style time functions. That, of course, is not a statement about the quality and power of `<chrono>`, maybe I should start using it :)

Comment: Can't you just do `std::tm tm = {0}`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, but both GCC and Clang will warn you about missing field initializer(s), see [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2CAxKb$0).

Comment: @Daniel : But I suspect `std::tm tm = { };` won't.

Comment: @ildjarn: Depends on the compiler, your version makes Clang happy but GCC still gives you [lots of warnings](http://liveworkspace.org/code/iUsXS$1).

Answer (score 7):

New answer for an old question.

Except for messing around with the archaic `std::tm`, C++11 has no good way of dealing with dates or datetime, with the exception of [boost Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time.html).  And there is one other library that I've been working on lately, that is highly tilted towards performance, compile-time type safety, and `chrono` compatibility.  As presented it only works with C++14, but if you back off some of the `constexpr`s, it will work with C++11.  It is header-only, and consists of only one header, and is documented [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  <del>It is light on its I/O capability.</del> (and now has extensive I/O capability)

But here is what it looks like for your example:

Oh, now that I look closely, and not knowing C#, I don't know whether `DateTime(4,5,2012)` refers to Apr 5, 2012, or May 4, 2012.  Both m/d/y and d/m/y formats are popularly used.  This is one of the problems my library addresses.  It accepts both formats unambiguously.  For this demo I'm going to assume you are writing in m/d/y format.  But I'll use both formats to reproduce your example:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
//     DateTime date1=new DateTime(4,5,2012);
//     DateTime date2=new DateTIme(7,8,2013);
//     int day1=date1.Days;
//     TimeSpan ts=d2-d1;
//     int diffDays=ts.Days;

    using namespace date;
    auto date1 = sys_days(apr/5/2012);     // m/d/y is ok
    auto date2 = sys_days(8_d/jul/2013);   // d/m/y is ok
                                           // y/m/d is also ok
    auto diffDays = date2 - date1;         // diffDays is a chrono::duration
    std::cout << diffDays.count() << '\n';
}
```

This will output:

```
459
```

And in C++14, this computation can actually be done at compile time:

```
constexpr auto date1 = sys_days(apr/5/2012);
constexpr auto date2 = sys_days(8_d/jul/2013);
constexpr auto diffDays = date2 - date1;
static_assert(diffDays == days{459}, "");
```

And that means that "date constants" can be both very readable and very efficient, compiling down to an "immediate load."

See [the documentation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) for a full description, tutorial and implementation.